# CSS3 PIE.js, using it for multiple items

Tags: jquery, css

Following this documentation, http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/ I was able to successfully apply the plugin to one element and make a CSS3 style work, however it doesn't work for more than one item.

```
//THIS WORK ON THE WRAPPER

 $(function() {
  if (window.PIE) {
     $('#wrapper').each(function() {
        PIE.attach(this);
     });   

  }
});

//SECOND FUNCTION FOR ANOTHER ID, DOES NOT WORK

$(function() {
  if (window.PIE) {
     $('#menu').each(function() {
        PIE.attach(this);
     });   

  }
});
```

Anyone have any experience with CSS3 PIE and making it work with more than one element?

Comment: never tried the js approach but when used in CSS I found that it causes some performance issues and also if your website is responsive with absolute positioned elements, sometimes there are display errors. I had to remove PIE at the end due to too many issues

Comment: Yeah, PIE does not scale well can can bring complex pages to a crawl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the elements with CSS3 styling didn't have a z-index applied. Once adding a z-index to both elements, PIE.js worked.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#wrapper')` implies that you're selecting an ID. Since IDs are supposed to be unique, it makes sense that you are only getting one element returned.